# Need help to understand spice statement

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, simulation, spice, hspice

I am hard time to understand below spice statement. I am using HSPICE

.measure AC cap_acc find par('-1* **II(VGA)** /(vac*hertz*2*3.14)') AT=100000hertz

Can anyone help with what II means ?

Thank you.

Comment: Which SPICE are you using? What about the statement don't you understand?

Comment: question edited.

Comment: Are you sure that's not a typo? It looks like it's meant to be the current through a voltage source with the reference designator `Vga`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

II(VGA) specifies that the imaginary part of the
current through VGA is printed.

Basically used in AC analysis.
Thank you.

Comment: HSPICE sure made this one a bit obscure. In LTspice for example, it's `im()`, which makes it a bit clearer that it's a function and what it does. Other SPICE simulators would have theirs, as well. You can select your answer (the check mark) so that future searches will show that this question has an accepted answer.